# Python Geograpy unable to run demo

Tags: python, nlp, geograpy

I am trying to run python's geograpy  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geograpy.

I installed geography using both

```
pip install geograpy
```

and

```
python setup.py install
```

I also made sure all the nltk's were installed properly.
I installed any dependencies used by geograpy.
I made the following changes to extraction.py

```
if (ne.node == 'GPE' or ne.node == 'PERSON') and ne[0][1] == 'NNP':

to

if (ne.label() == 'GPE' or ne.label() == 'PERSON') and ne[0][1] == 'NNP':
```

The demo code I am running is

```
import geograpy
url = 'http://www.gutenberg.ca/ebooks/doyleac-casebookofsherlockholmes/doyleac-casebookofsherlockholmes-00-h.html'

places = geograpy.get_place_context(url=url)

print places.country_mentions
print places.region_mentions
print places.city_mentions
```

However, I am getting this error

```
    if (ne.label() == 'GPE' or ne.label() == 'PERSON') and ne[0][1] == 'NNP':
AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'label'
```

And if i change the extraction.py back to

```
if (ne.node == 'GPE' or ne.node == 'PERSON') and ne[0][1] == 'NNP':
```

I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\geograpy-0.3.7-py2.7.egg\geograpy\places.py", line 174, in set_cities
    self.country_cities[country.name] = []
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I will also mention that I was using NLTK 3, but geograpy downgraded it to NLTK2.0.5.

Someone out there PLEASEEEEEEE help! THANKS

Comment: you might want to use geograpy3 instead https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. It just requires to change the correct variable name in palces.py file located in
C:\Users\Naima\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\geograpy\places.py
Go to the line 174 in places.py file and replace the country.name with country_name as follows:

```
 self.country_cities[country_name] = []
```

Hope this works!